# Create a new project type in netbeans module

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-plugins

Let's say I need to develop a plugin for a given technology not supported by netbeans, how do I register a new project type for this technology?

The user may want to create a new project using the project wizard, I've maneged to create a project template, but this requires the template to be based on an existing project type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [tutorial](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-projecttype.html) on creating a new project type in netbeans 6.7 or 6.8.